# JdbcTemplate : Issue with dynamically configurable query arguments

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a query as below:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM SCHEM1.TAB1 WHERE COL3=? AND COL4=?
```

I am executing above query in my java class as:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> resultList = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, (Object[]) queryParams);
```

Issue is I am getting `queryParams` at runtime from a text properties file as below:

```
2013-03-28||helloWorld
```

As seen in above line, the properties file has arguments to a sql. All arguments are delimited by a double pipe.

I am reading this line into a `String[]` by using the split method on the pipe delimiter.

So my resultant `queryParams` String array would be:

`String[]` `queryParams` where `String[0]` would be `2013-03-28` and `String[1]` would be `helloWorld`

When I am passing this `String[]` directly to templates `queryForList` method by casting it as `Object[]` as mentioned at the start of this post, and when my log4j is set to `debug` mode, I am getting termination on the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: SQLWarning chain holds value that is not a SQLWarning
at java.sql.SQLWarning.getNextWarning(SQLWarning.java:91)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.handleWarnings(JdbcTemplate.java:1260)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:636)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:665)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:673)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:796)
at com.hsbc.pb.it.re.db.dao.impl.ReconDaoImplNew.getColumnList(MyClass.java:362)
```

A line just above this error in the console mentions:

```
SQLWarning ignored: SQL state 'null', error code '0', message [Input data type mismatch, see chained exceptions; will retry execution using describe input information.  Please change application to use an input data type that matches the database column type as required by JDBC semantics.]
```

However, this code works correctly when I am setting the log4j level to `info`.

What is the cause of this termination ?

How to resolve it ?

Is it to do with parameter type (as in, I am passing String to queryForList when the expected column is Date) ? If so, how can I correctly format a String to expected type before passing to `queryForList` method ?

I can change the properties file to something like:

```
2013-06-28,DATE||helloWorld,VARCHAR
```

Where information on the type of the value is also passed along. But using this info, how can I convert the String to given type -- Is such approach a nice solution ?

Why the error is not coming when log4j is in `info` mode ?

Thanks for reading!

Please let me know if any details are missing.

Comment: `Input data type mismatch` : so have you convert '2013-06-28' to a Date Object in queryParams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `2013-06-28,DATE||helloWorld,VARCHAR` is a good way

you can make some handlers to parse it,like:

```
Map<String,IConvert> converts =  new HashMap<String, IConvert>(){
    put("varchar",new StringConver());
    put("date",new DateConver());
}
//then
converts.get(type).toParam(string)
```

what I guess  Why the error is not coming when log4j is in info mode, the error is coming with `debug mode`! The jdbcDriver will not throw exception when you setString() to a date type,but will return a warnings like 'Code: 1292 SQL State: HY000 --- Incorrect date value' 
Maybe the  dbcTemplate using debug mode to treat it.